# What kind of stress is this?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, ipa, stress, phonetic-symbols

I found the word "ice-free" is pronounced /ˈˌaɪsˈˌfri/ in Oxford English Dictionary, but what kind of stress is this? Should it be called 'there are two primary stresses and two secondary stresses?'

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means it is pronounced either /ˈaɪsˌfri/ or /ˌaɪsˈfri/. This notation of "¦" standing for "primary or secondary stress" was devised in *Webster's Third* (1961) by its pronunciation editor, Edward Artin (according to [Windsor Lewis](http://www.yek.me.uk/reviewodp.html)).

Comment: It’s not actually true, though, is it? I mean, does anyone have primary stress on _free_ in _ice-free_? Sounds completely alien to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet What about in e.g. *The sea is ice-free today*?

Comment: @TKR Unquestionably primary stress on _ice_ and secondary stress on _free_ to me. There are cases where there’s actual variation, free or otherwise, like the _-teen_ numbers; but I’ve never heard anyone pronounce any _-free_ compound with primary stress on _free_. (Not counting contrastive stress, obviously, because anything can be stressed anywhere for contrast.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I hear lots of "ˌiceˈfree" [here](https://youglish.com/pronounce/ice-free/english). It's a bit hard to make heads or tails when it's used attributively, but equal stress suggests a stress shift has occurred and the word canonically has primary stress on the second element. When predicative, it could be argued that it's two separate words rather than a compound (as Obama sounds), but I can't even find "ˈiceˌfree" [here](https://youglish.com/pronounce/be%20ice%20free/english).

Comment: @Nardog Obama’s sounds like ˈiceˈfree to me, with two pretty equal stresses; all the others (of the twelve or so I listened to) decidedly sound like ˈiceˌfree, with stronger stress on _ice_. The last one (predicative) does seem to have an unusual level of stress on _free_, making it sound contrastive to me (even though context dictates it’s not) – but even there the stress on _ice_ still sounds primary to me, more ˈiceˈfree (or maybe ˈiceˈˈfree, if we may so abuse IPA) than ˌiceˈfree.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That's... weird. With all due respect I wonder if your L1 is interfering with your perception of English stress. Does your perception of [these](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/ballet) [demonstrations](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cliche) [of](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/frustrating) [words](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/spectator)  match the transcriptions?

Comment: @Nardog I don’t think it’s other-language interference, because English is my L1 (along with Danish, which has very similar stress patterns). Those examples all match my perception exactly, except inasmuch as they don’t mark the secondary stress at all – I just couldn’t think of any good ones before. _Ballet_ and _cliché_ are probably the best comparison here: ˈbalˌlet and ˈcliˌché have the exact same stress pattern as ˈiceˌfree_ to me, but ˌbaˈllet and ˌcliˈché have a distinctly different stress pattern than any of the _ice-free_’s in the videos.

Comment: If both elements of a compound have the same level of stress in running speech, then it is the second that will be considered to bear the primary stress because it's the one that receives the intonational falling tone.

Comment: I think I use phrasal stress in "ice-free," with more or equal stress on the second member.  It is the same stress as "town hall" and different from the stress pattern on "townhouse."

Comment: Just going off my own intuition, I think that if I say "the sea is ice-free today," I put the primary stress on "free," but if I say "the Arctic saw its first ice-free summer," I put the primary stress on "ice." Saying "ice-free" in isolation, I'd put the primary stress on "free," unless "ice" is contrastive. Would anyone like me to see if I can record an audio file of me speaking all this?

Comment: @TannerSwett That describes my (AmEng) speech too, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet How about in “The path must be ice-free”?

Comment: @Araucaria-him I don’t see how that would differ from “The sea is ice-free today” (from TKR’s comment further up).

Comment: @Nardog Considered… by whom? By speakers in general, or by phoneticians (for whatever presumably systematic reason)? If both elements have the same level of stress, as a speaker, I would consider them to have equal stress, since they both carry the contextually significant tone contour. But then I have no systematic opposition to a compound having two primary stresses.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, for me, *ice-free* has two stresses, where the second is likely to appear more prominent if it has the tonic syllable. But like *champagne*, such words undergo 'stress shift' if next to a following syllable that's stressed. So we'd normally perceive "cham**pagne**", but if the following syllable's also stressed the first is perceived as more prominent: "**'cham**pagne 'cocktail""

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, by phoneticians, the likes of Wells, Roach, and Upton. You do you as a speaker, but a lexicographer would assign different levels of stress to the word as a lexical item because they record *lexical* stress.