# Is there an IPA symbol to represent both primary or secondary stress?

Tags: ipa, stress

I was just wondering if there is an IPA symbol to represent stress in general, be that primary or secondary stress, just one symbol for both?

Comment: See also this question (kind of inverse question to the current one): https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/44321/9781

Comment: Are you talking about the transcription of an isolated word, or the transcription of connected speech?

Comment: Are you talking about the transcription of an isolated word, or the transcription of connected speech?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IPA includes symbols for primary stress /ˈ/ and secondary stress /ˌ/, but does not have any symbol for unspecified stress.

Ad hoc extension e.g. /¦/ may be used, but these are not officially part of the IPA, and may require explanation in the accompanying text.